# Players spawn in the wall on DarkRP

Tags: garrys-mod

I am creating a DarkRP server, but players spawn in the wall in rp_downtown_v2 (across from the police station) and somewhat in the ground in rp_downtown_v4c_v2 (in the hotel).

Answer (score 1):

This is due to an error with the jobs you have made.

The point in which you spawn at is considered the "Origin" (in map making terms) and is located at 0z, 0y, 0x.

The most simple answer I can give is for you to look at any errors you have made with a job. You should consider using a job generator if you are not the best as in coding.